# Media queries not working ?But in other pages they are working

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize, media-queries

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

    <style>
        html{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
        body{margin:0px;padding:0px;box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        .navigation-bar{
            display:block;width:100%;position:fixed;background-color:rgba(55,55,55,1);
            color:white;box-sizing: border-box;margin:0px auto;text-align: center;padding:0px;
            }

        .navigation-list li{display:inline-block;max-width:180px;margin-right:auto;list-style-type: none;padding:10px;position:relative;font-size:25px;border-bottom:0px solid white; transition:border-bottom 0.3s;
        }

        .navigation-list li:hover{border-bottom:2px solid white;
        }
        .navigation-list li:after{margin:auto; content:"";width:0%;height:3px;display:block;background:transparent;transition:width 0.5s,background-color 0.5s
        }
        .navigation-list li:hover:after{width:100%;background-color: aqua;
        }
        .nav{background-color: black;width:500px;display:block;position: relative;}
        @media only screen and(max-width:520px){

            .navigation-bar{top:0px;left:0px;width:200px;}

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">

        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Directory</li>
            <li>PlacesToExplore</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>NearestPlaces</li>                
        </ul>
    </div>    
</body>
```

The media queries in this page are not working but they are working in my other pages in the same browser. I want the navigation bar to be at the left when the browser is resized below 520px.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries working correct. The problem in css, you can specify each li like block.

```
@media (max-width:520px){
 .navigation-list li{
  display: block;
 }
}
```

Comment: It worked only by changing "@media only screen and(max-width:520px){}" to just "@media(max-width)" .But i can't understand why is it so. In other pages where i used "@media only screen and " they just worked fine ,but now it requires other syntax?